# The tags [svn] and [subversion] should be synonyms

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tag-synonyms

I think the tags [svn](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/svn) and [subversion](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/subversion) should be synonyms.

Not just merged, because authors might search for "svn" and not "subversion", and vice versa.

The primary one should be [subversion](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/subversion), because it seems to be the canonical name, and it’s [what Wikipedia uses as article name](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apache_Subversion). (Well, Wikipedia uses "Apache Subversion", so we could also use [apache-subversion](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/apache-subversion) instead, similar to how we have [microsoft-word](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/microsoft-word), but I have no opinion on this.)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Good find. Merge performed and synonym created. I've kept the tag name `subversion`, as noone will search for `apache-subversion` – and if you look at the bottom of that Wikipedia page, even Wikipedia refers to it simply as "Subversion" in its listings ;)